# После изменения background пропала анимация и вид кнопки

Tags: android

После того, как в настройках кнопки установил цвет (`android:background="#FFFFFF"`), пропала анимация нажатия и 3D вид кнопки.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В подобных вопросах всегда полезно приводить код, который отвечает за функциональность, описанную в посте. Так вы повысите вероятность ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всей вашей анимацией и 3-d видом занимается селектор, назначенный бэкграунду.

В андроид бэкграунд может быть очень сложным и выполнять много работы, возможностей системой предоставлено [достаточно на все случаи жизни](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) .

Вы установили свой бэкграунд, который устанавливает только цвет - для всех состояний. Естественно, что ничего, кроме цвета он не показывает.

Исправить это можно:

1. Вернув все обратно - установив преждний бэкграунд. Цвет фона при этом не изменится.
2. Написать свой селектор для бэкграунда с анимациями и прочим и указав там нужный цвет фона.
3. Скопировать ранее назначенный бэкграунд в проект и немного модифицировать его, изменив цвет на нужный - предпочтительное решение.

PS: если в качестве элементов оформления фона используются изображения, а не графические xml-примитивы, то эти изображения придется перерисовать с нужным цветом.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать selector.

Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#c64333" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#dd4b39" />
    </shape>
</item>
```